# Why is the 'Google Chrome Renderer' multi-processes, not multi-threaded?

Tags: multithreading, google-chrome, thread-safety

Every time I load a browser tag in Chrome on my mac, the application forks another process. This seems to be different from how firefox or Safari work. What was the reason why Google stayed away from multi-threading in this case? The problem to be solved here (rendering multiple pages at once would seem in my mind to be a prime candidate for muti-threading, or?

Comment: I think it's so pages can't crash other pages..

Comment: @MikeChristensen According to [THIS](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/multi-process-architecture) you are correct.

Comment: autsch.... -2 in 3mins a new record!! ;)

Comment: Don't worry, that's not anywhere *close* to the record..

Comment: @MikeChristensen Indeed it also seems that separate processes provide a sandbox against IO r/w. It seems that unix forking is becoming more popular.

Comment: The problem is the question isn't really coding specific. Usually questions here are how can i solve this problem, or why does this code do that. But i am sure you know that already.

Comment: @MikeChristensen You should add your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Ben been coding for 10 hours straight, got bored...

Comment: @JacksonHenley, You german?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Running each page (or tab) in a separate process allows Chrome to provide a bit more security against page rendering bugs, as well as browser plug-ins that run within a process.  Basically, if one page crashes, it won't affect other tabs.  Instead, you'll get an "Aw Snap!" message.

[image]

From the [docs](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/multi-process-architecture):

> We use separate processes for browser tabs to protect the overall
>   application from bugs and glitches in the rendering engine. We also
>   restrict access from each rendering engine process to others and to
>   the rest of the system. In some ways, this brings to web browsing the
>   benefits that memory protection and access control brought to
>   operating systems.

Comment: If a computer has 4 processors, so how many "processes" can we have? Is there any limit of it. Thanks